# UDPROS Protocol and Lost Packet/Sequencing Algorithms

Tags: ros, udpros, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Community,

My recent adventure into development of a Java based UDPROS protocol left me with some unanswered questions that will be beneficial for the ROS Community to discuss, and create a specification of some sort.

**Single Packet Message issues:**

- **Issue 1:** Out of Order message handling.
- **Issue 2:** Dropped message handling.

**Multi-Packet Message issues:**

- **Issue 1:** Dropped Datagram Packets in a single message.
- **Issue 2:** Out of sequence datagram packet handling.
- **Issue 3:** Timeout before dropping message entirely, or passing on received data with missing packets.
- **Option 1:** Drop entire message immediately if a received datagram contains a new message id, and the preceding multi-packet message is incomplete.
- **Option 2:** Wait for messages to complete in any/every order until a timeout is reached regardless of order until the entire message is received, and pass message into a topic queue. Drop message if message times out.

Both options have advantages depending on the topic type, and robot requirements. Option 2 requires more processing power and energy usage to maintain timeouts, and Option 2 handles out of sequence/out of order messages/packets. Option 1 performs more quicker/efficiently, at the cost of more lost messages. Both options seem like they could be valuable if they are implemented in the UDPROS API.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61318/udpros-protocol-and-lost-packet/sequencing-algorithms/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the current UDPROS I believe Option 1 is implemented as it is the simplest and provides the low latency performance for which most people select UDP.  If you want to start a discussion I suggest you restart this on ros-users@code.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thanks, I emailed ros-users@code.ros.org.